# Django | TypeError at /users/user_newPassword/qSeiNzs9H... | post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token'

Tags: python, django

Para que el usuario pueda resetear el password, clica en un enlace "resetear password" envía un email al usuario con un token corréctamente. En el email recibido por el usuario (que también contiene un token que se coloca en el enlace que clicará el usuario para enviarlo al formulario de crear nuevo password) se clica en un botón que lleva al formulario para crear nuevo password (contiene dos input para hacerlos coincidir). Tras rellenar los dos campos y darle a aceptar devuelve el siguiente error. Creo que en la View (CreateNewPasswordView) algo no estoy haciendo bien. ¿Qué sucede?

**Pasos:**

1. Usuario clica en "Resetear password"
2. Usuario rellena un formulario con un input email para recibir correo de reseteo de password
3. Usuario recibe un email (user + token + fecha)
4. Usuario clica en enlace dominio/token (dominio que contiene token)
5. Usuario rellena formulario con dos input (password1 y password2)
6. La view CreateNewPaswordView debe validad el password, comprobar el token y guardar el nuevo password. (**Aquí sale el error.**)

**Error:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Views.py > CreateNewPasswordView**

```
class CreateNewPasswordView(View):
template_name = "users/crear_password.html"
success_url = reverse_lazy('home_app:home')

def get(self, request, token):
    return render(request, self.template_name, {})

def post(self, request, token):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']
        token = request.POST['token']
        if password1 == password2:
            t = TokenToUser.user.filter(token=token).last()
            u = Profile.objects.filter(user=t).last()
            u.password=password1
            u.save()
            messages.success(request, 'La nueva contraseña ha sido creada con éxito. Ya puedes iniciar sesión con la nueva contraseña')
            template_name2 = "users/login.html"
            return render(request, self.template_name2, {})
        else:
            messages.success(request, 'Las contraseñas deben coincidir. Prueba de nuevo.')
            return render(request, self.template_name, {})
```

**Views.py > UserResetView**

```
class UserResetView(View):
    template_name = "users/reset.html"
    form_class = ResetPasswordForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home_app:home')

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {})

    def post(self, request):
        email = request.POST.get('email', None)
        user = User.objects.filter(email__exact=email).last()
        if user:
            token = get_random_string(length=34)

            url_reset = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000{path}'.format(domain=settings.BASE_URL,path=reverse_lazy('users_app:user_newPassword', kwargs={'token': token}))
            context = {'url_reset': url_reset, 'user': user.username, 'date': now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}
            html_message = render_to_string('users/email_template.html', context)
            plain_message = strip_tags(html_message)
            texto_email=send_mail(subject='Reset de contraseña', message=plain_message, from_email='ejemplo@gmail.com',
                          recipient_list=[email], html_message=html_message)
            if texto_email:
                user_token = TokenToUser(user=user, token=token, date=now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
                user_token.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Ha sido enviado un email a su correo para resetear el password.')
            else:
                messages.error(request, '¡ups! Algo sucedió mal.')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'El email introducido no existe. Pruebe de nuevo o regístrese como nuevo usuario.')
        return redirect(reverse_lazy('users_app:user-reset'))
```

**Template:**

```
<form class="form-signin" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
      <div class="text-center mb-4">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Crear password</h1>
      </div>
    
        <input type="password" name="password1" class="form-control form-control-lg mb-3" placeholder="Nueva contraseña">
        <input type="password" name="password2" class="form-control form-control-lg mb-3" placeholder="Repita nueva constraseña">

      <button style="background-color:#250F64; color:white" class="btn btn-lg btn-block mb-3" type="submit">Aceptar</button>
    </form>
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views

app_name = 'users_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('',
        views.UserLoginView.as_view(),
        name='user-login',
    ),
    path('user_registration/',
        views.UserRegistrationView.as_view(),
        name='user-registration',
    ),
    path('user_logout/',
        views.UserLogoutView.as_view(),
        name='user-logout',
    ),
    path('user_reset/',
        views.UserResetView.as_view(),
        name='user-reset',
    ),
    path('user_newPassword/<str:token>',
        views.CreateNewPasswordView.as_view(),
        name='user_newPassword',
    ),
]
```

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class TokenToUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=34, null=True, blank=False)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                verbose_name='Registration date')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: Hola, Ret. Comparte tu archivo de **urls.py**, por favor.

Comment: Ya he añadido urls.py Gracias revliscano.

Comment: Así, a bote pronto, parece que solo necesitas editar la lista de parámetros de `CreateNewPasswordView.post()` para que pueda recibir el argumento token.

Comment: Parece que me acerco poco a poco (si observas el post). Claro que el get lo hago al token del modelo TokenToUser, pero debo modificar el password del otro model Profile. Supongo que con el token debo buscar el user y después filtrar ese user en el otro modelo para hacer save() del nuevo password. (O algo asi...)

Comment: O sea, pero es que de lo que se queja Django es que él está tratando de pasarle un argumento con nombre `token` a tu vista `CreateNewPasswordView` en medio de una petición HTTP POST. Por lo cual lo que creo que debes hacer es, sencillamente, colocar: `def post(self, request, token): ...` en la clase `CreateNewPasswordView`.

Comment: Así es. Tras añadir el parametro token a esa View, ese error no sale. Sale otro que he indicado en un nuevo post. Gracias.